# Number of hydrogen bonds of organic compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrogen-bond

How to count the organic molecules ' hydrogen bonds in average?

What are the numbers of hydrogen bonds formed among alcohols ,alkanoic acids ,aldehyde , ketones , amine ,amide , and ether when they are dissolved in water?

Comment: Well, that's simple: (number of hydrogens linked to highly electronegative atoms like N or O) + (number of lone pairs).

Answer (score -1):

Hint you could write down general formula for eg for alcohols it $C_nH_{2n}O$ and also  due to covalent bonds the hydrocarbons arent dissolved in water.

Comment: but like water ,when i count the H bonds in average , it should be two ,but if i add up the number of H linked to O and its lone pair ,it becomes four ,why does this occur ??